# Using a variable in stylesheet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

I have a multi-tenancy Rails app, where each tenant has an `base_color` attribute which contains a hex color code. I have a `variables.css.scss` file which contains Sass variables which are used in several other stylesheet files.

Now I want to use the `tenant.base_color` variable to set the Sass variable `$base_color` in `variables.css.scss`, so the base color of the app changes according to the logged in tenant. Is this at all possible?

I tried to rename the file to `variables.css.scss.erb` and then use this:

```
$base-color: <%= current_tenant.base_color %>;
```

But this doesn't work, I get an `File to import not found or unreadable: variables.css.scss.` error.

Comment: It's not possible. `css.scss` files are compiled to `css` once (when you run `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`), so you can't make them dependant on some dynamic values. I guess you'd have to use inline css instead.

Comment: That's a pity, but now it works by doing this. Can you move this as answer, then I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible. `css.scss` files are compiled to css once (when you run `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`), so you can't make them dependant on some dynamic values. I guess you'd have to use inline css instead.